# How can I make a stub to return any negative number?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

If there is at least one sample product available for this customer and the order amount did match a configured limit (the missing amount is negative) just show the Edit button. The logic is simple, how can I make the testing for any negative number, not just -1?

```
// function to be tested
showEditButton: function () {
    return !this.getSamples().isEmpty() && this.getMissingAmount().getValue() <= 0;
}

// my lame test here
describe('showEditButton()', function () {
    it('should be true if the missing amount is negative and at least one available sample', function () {
        var samples = new Samples({}, {}, {});

        sinon.stub(samples, 'getMissingAmount').returns({
            getValue: sinon.stub().returns(-1) // I need any negative number here :(
        });

        sinon.stub(samples, 'getSamples').returns({
            isEmpty: sinon.stub().returns(false)
        });

        expect(samples.showEditButton()).to.be.true;
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the intent? There's no such thing as "any negative number", so I am not sure of the exact solution you are looking for. Tests cannot be written with an 'imaginary' number like "any negative number", so if you want a very precise test, you can try adding many more checks for some random numbers you hardcode, or if you really want, a Math.random() passed into the stub can work as well

Answer (score 0):

> If there is at least one sample product available for this customer and the order amount did match a configured limit (the missing amount is negative) just show the Edit button.

i don't believe it will matter to make tests for **any** negative number, not for `showEditButton` at least, so you can try to make `getMissingAmount` to return the difference or else return `0`.

the only thing you need to test is the missing amount the cases are just two its `value <= 0` or  `>=1`.

```
describe('showEditButton()', function () {
    it('if the missing amount is negative and at least one available sample, showEditButton should be true', function () {
        var samples = new Samples({}, {}, {});

        sinon.stub(samples, 'getMissingAmount').returns({
            getValue: sinon.stub().returns(-1);
        });

        sinon.stub(samples, 'getSamples').returns({
            isEmpty: sinon.stub().returns(false);
        });

        expect(samples.showEditButton()).to.be.true;
    });

    it('if the missing amount is NOT negative and at least one available sample, showEditButton should be false', function () {
        var samples = new Samples({}, {}, {});

        sinon.stub(samples, 'getMissingAmount').returns({
            getValue: sinon.stub().returns(1);
        });

        sinon.stub(samples, 'getSamples').returns({
            isEmpty: sinon.stub().returns(false);
        });

        expect(samples.showEditButton()).to.be.false;
    });
});
```

You can make the test for `getMissingAmount().getValue()` functions to return different results every time its called.

```
// stub get getValue()
fn.onCall(0).returns(-100);
fn.onCall(1).returns(-50);
fn.onCall(2).returns(-25);
fn.returns(3);

fn(); // -100
fn(); // -50
fn(); // -25
fn(); // 3
fn(); // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you can't really test with 'any negative number'. For situations like these, you usually want to test values around the boundary and assume the rest will work. In this case, these values would be -1, 0, and 1.

As for accomplishing this in mocha, you have a few approaches. You can group all of these cases into one test, like so:

```
describe('showEditButton()', function () {
    it('should be true if missing amount is negative and at least one available sample', function() {
        var samples = new Samples({}, {}, {});
        sinon.stub(samples, 'getSamples').returns({
            isEmpty: sinon.stub().returns(false)
        });
        sinon.stub(samples, 'getMissingAmount').returns({
            getValue: sinon.stub()
                .onFirstCall().returns(-1)
                .onSecondCall().returns(0)
                .onThirdCall().returns(1)
        });

        expect(samples.showEditButton()).to.be.true;
        expect(samples.showEditButton()).to.be.false;
        expect(samples.showEditButton()).to.be.false;
    });
});
```

Alternatively-- and more correctly, if you're trying to follow best practices for unit tests-- you can explicitly give each case its own test, like so:

```
describe('showEditButton()', function () {
    var samples, missingAmount;

    beforeEach(function() {
        samples = new Samples({}, {}, {});
        missingAmount = { getValue: sinon.stub() };

        sinon.stub(samples, 'getSamples').returns({
            isEmpty: sinon.stub().returns(false)
        });
        sinon.stub(samples, 'getMissingAmount').returns(missingAmount);
    });

    it('should be true if missing amount is negative and at least one available sample', function() {
        missingAmount.getValue.returns(-1);

        expect(samples.showEditButton()).to.be.true;
    });

    it('should be false if missing amount is zero and at least one available sample', function() {
        missingAmount.getValue.returns(0);

        expect(samples.showEditButton()).to.be.false;
    });

    it('should be false if missing amount is positive and at least one available sample', function() {
        missingAmount.getValue.returns(1);

        expect(samples.showEditButton()).to.be.false;
    });
});
```

Though, in neither case have you tested the check for `isEmpty`. For that, you can do something like this:

```
describe('showEditButton()', function () {
    var samples, getSamplesResult, missingAmount;

    beforeEach(function() {
        samples = new Samples({}, {}, {});
        missingAmount = { getValue: sinon.stub() };
        getSamplesResult = { isEmpty: sinon.stub() };

        sinon.stub(samples, 'getSamples').returns(getSamplesResult);
        sinon.stub(samples, 'getMissingAmount').returns(missingAmount);
    });

    context('no available samples', function() {
        it('should be false without getting missing amount', function() {
            getSamplesResult.isEmpty.returns(true);

            expect(samples.getSamples()).to.be.false;
            expect(samples.getMissingAmount.callCount).to.equal(0);
        });
    });

    context('at least one available sample', function() {
        beforeEach(function() {
            getSamplesResult.isEmpty.returns(false);
        });

        it('should be true if missing amount is negative', function() {
            missingAmount.getValue.returns(-1);

            expect(samples.showEditButton()).to.be.true;
        });

        it('should be false if missing amount is zero', function() {
            missingAmount.getValue.returns(0);

            expect(samples.showEditButton()).to.be.false;
        });

        it('should be false if missing amount is positive', function() {
            missingAmount.getValue.returns(1);

            expect(samples.showEditButton()).to.be.false;
        });
    });
});
```

Note that `context` is simply an alias for `describe`, which you can use in situations like this to make the intent of the block a bit more clear to readers.

Finally, if you want to get really fancy, you can use plain JS functions to "parametrize" your test cases. I usually don't go this far, but it's possible if you want it:

```
describe('showEditButton()', function () {
    var samples, getSamplesResult, missingAmount;

    beforeEach(function() {
        samples = new Samples({}, {}, {});
        missingAmount = { getValue: sinon.stub() };
        getSamplesResult = { isEmpty: sinon.stub() };

        sinon.stub(samples, 'getSamples').returns(getSamplesResult);
        sinon.stub(samples, 'getMissingAmount').returns(missingAmount);
    });

    context('no available samples', function() {
        it('should be false without getting missing amount', function() {
            getSamplesResult.isEmpty.returns(true);

            expect(samples.getSamples()).to.be.false;
            expect(samples.getMissingAmount.callCount).to.equal(0);
        });
    });

    context('at least one available sample', function() {
        beforeEach(function() {
            getSamplesResult.isEmpty.returns(false);
        });

        testCase(-1, true, 'negative');
        testCase(0, false, 'zero');
        testCase(1, false, 'positive');

        function testCase(value, expected, valueType) {
            it(`should be ${expected} if missing amount is ${valueType}`, function() {
                missingAmount.getValue.returns(value);

                expect(samples.showEditButton()).to.equal(expected);
            })
        }
    });
});
```